# Use Exchange PowerShell to count old emails in inbox folder

Tags: powershell-2.0, exchangewebservices

Does anyone know of a PowerShell script that uses EWS to look into a user's Exchange 2010 SP3 Inbox and get a count of email messages and the sizes older than 60 days for example?  I can't believe no one has been able to do this.  I see a lot of people asking how to do this.  Help please :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few example on this http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/reporting-on-item-age-count-and-size-in.html and http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/creating-mailbox-folder-growth-map-with.html

Specifically for what you want to do something like this should work

```cs
## Get the Mailbox to Access from the 1st commandline argument

$MailboxName = $args[0]
$DateFrom = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

## Load Managed API dll  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"  

## Set Exchange Version  
$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  

## Create Exchange Service Object  
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

#Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
$psCred = Get-Credential  
$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($psCred.UserName.ToString(),$psCred.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
$service.Credentials = $creds      

#Credentials Option 2  
#service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  

## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
## Create a compilation environment
$Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
$Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
$Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
$Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
$Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
$Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
$TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
$TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

#CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
"Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   

#CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

#$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
#$service.Url = $uri    

## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  

#$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 

# Bind to the Inbox Folder
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)   
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
#Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items    
$ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(250)  
$psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::IdOnly)  
$psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Size)
$psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived)
$psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeCreated)
$ivItemView.PropertySet = $psPropset

$sfItemSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsLessThan([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived,$DateFrom) 

$rptObj = "" | Select Mailbox,TotalNumber,TotalSize
$rptObj.Mailbox = $MailboxName
$rptObj.TotalNumber = 0
$rptObj.TotalSize = [Int64]0

$fiItems = $null    
do{    
    $fiItems = $service.FindItems($Inbox.Id,$sfItemSearchFilter,$ivItemView)    
    #[Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)  
    foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){
            $rptObj.TotalNumber += 1
            $rptObj.TotalSize += [Int64]$Item.Size
    }    
    $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count    
}while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)

$rptObj | select Mailbox,TotalNumber,@{label="TotalSize(MB)";expression={[math]::Round($_.TotalSize/1MB,2)}}
```